# How can I view modENCODE data faster?

Tags: bioinformatics, lab-techniques

I am trying to view several data tracks in the modENCODE GBrowse genomic browser. However, the site is so slow, it is practically unworkable. Is there a faster way to explore the data?

Comment: I have no experience with this, but apparently you can download it: http://www.modencode.org/publications/faq/#How_do_I_access_modENCODE_data.3F

Comment: Download the data and parse locally..

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- You can always [download the data](ftp://data.modencode.org/) (as @WYSIWYG has suggested in the comment).
- Transfer the data to [Galaxy](https://usegalaxy.org/)
- Convert and export the selection of your choice.

[image]

Source: http://modencode.oicr.on.ca/fgb2/gbrowse/fly/